# Why not override instead of using abstract class?

Tags: java, abstract-class, overriding

This might be a simple question for many but has confused me. I am picking an example from Kathy Sierra that shows the utility of Abstract Classes but I am unable to understand the overall importance of abstract classes.

**Example**
We have an abstract class `Car` with abstract methods - `power()` & `topSpeed()`. These methods are implemented in sub classes *BMW*, *Volkswagen* and *Audi*.

**My question is -** why do we need to have the abstract class `Car` in the first place to customize methods for each car type? Why not have these two methods in any one of these car subtypes, say BMW and then other two - Volkswagen and Audi - can simply override these methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By making a method abstract, it means that people have to implement it. You require people to do so and it is impossible for people to forget to do so, as it will fail to compile if they do.

The `@override` annotation exists for a very similar reason, by marking a method as `@override` you get an error if (for example) you typed the method name wrong and aren't actually overriding something.

In many ways the abstract class is half way between an interface and a normal class - it defines what you need to do to use it in the same way an interface does, but it also handles some of the implementation for you.

Classes can only extend one other class. They can implement any number of interfaces.

For example you might have `MotorVehicle` inherited by `Car`, `Motorbike` and `Train` - but then you might have a `Steerable` interface implemented by `Car`, `Motorbike` and `Pedalbike`.

To answer the question in the comments:

> If there is an Interface "I" having method m() which is implemented by class "A" and another class "B" wants to access the method m(), what is the need of interface here. Can we simply not implement that method in class A?

You can - but if on the other hand class `B` wants to access the method `m()` in both a class `A` and class `C` (where A and C don't inherit from each other or a common class containing m()) then the way to do that is to specify a common interface I and class B uses the interface type, I, not the types A and C at all.

Also remember that interfaces can be used between packages and libraries. For example *Listener* and *Strategy* patterns make heavy use of interfaces. When the Java developers wrote `JButton` (for example) the `ActionLstener` is specified as an Interface to provide maximum flexibility to people using `JButtons` in the future.

Comment: Thanks @Tim B. This raises another question in my mind. As you said, the abstract class makes sure that subclasses implement methods in it, but then what's the utility of interfaces? If there is an Interface "I" having method m() which is implemented by class "A" and another class "B" wants to access the method m(), what is the need of interface here. Can we simply not implement that method in class A?

Answer (score 1):

> Why not have these two methods in any one of these car subtypes, say BMW and then other two - Volkswagen and Audi - can simply override these methods?

Wouldn't that require `Volkswagen` and `Audi` to inherit from `BMW`?  That wouldn't be correct, since those aren't BMWs.

The abstract base class and its abstract methods form a kind of contract which inheriting objects must implement.  There's no such thing as a concrete `Car` that isn't a more specific type.  But all concrete types share commonalities.  The abstract `Car` enforces those commonalities, allowing specific types to be treated as generic instances of `Car` when needed.

For example, if you have code which needs a `Car` on which it will invoke the `Drive()` method, that code doesn't care what *kind* of `Car` it gets.  It will `Drive()` any `Car`.  So it accepts an abstract type so that anything which implements that type can be used:

```
UseACar(Car car)
{
    car.Drive();
}

// elsewhere

BMW myCar = new BMW();
UseACar(myCar);
```

Without this enforcement of the contract, a statically-typed and compiled language would have no way of guaranteeing that `.Drive()` exists on the object.  You'd need to create a `UseAX()` method for every possible kind of car, each accepting a different type.  Using polymorphism like this allows you to create a single, more generic method which works on any instance of the abstract type.

Answer (score 0):

So that you can write code that deals with `Car`s without knowing what kind of car it is:

```
public void PrintTopSpeed(Car car)
{
    System.out.println("This car's top speed is " + car.topSpeed());
}
```

If the `Car` class didn't define `topSpeed()`, this code wouldn't compile. You'd have to have a different version of this print function for each of your BMW, Volkswagen, Audi, etc. derived classes. This is perhaps the most basic concept in object-oriented programming, so you really need to master it. Base classes allow objects to share common behavior, and allow code to be written to use that behavior without any knowledge of what specific type of object it's dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism is the answer. If you don't have methods power() and topSpeed() in the abstract class you can't do things like this :

```
List<Car> cars;
cars.add(new Porshe());
cars.add(new Ford());

for(Car car : cars){
    System.out.println(car.topSpeed());
}
```

You would have to handle lot of thing your self if you have only custom methods in your subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

This is called abstraction. Methods in abstract class are considered as protocol so that car makers should not violate.

Answer (score 0):

abstraction is great when the original programmer/architect want's to allow customized behavior to some base class and ensure that the consuming programmer implements the required methods.